# I am looking for project id on GitHub similar to project id on GitLab

Tags: github-api, github-actions

Is there a way to check for project id on GitHub similar to GitLab? I searched all settings but did not find the project id. Wondering if it's permissions that are causing me not to see the properties or there is no project id in GitHub.

Really appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Each Github repository has an ID and many other fields you can obtain by consuming the [Github API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository).

As explained on the link above, you can use the following service:

[image]

To get all kind of datas about the repository:

```html
{
  "id": 1296269,
  "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMjk2MjY5",
  "name": "Hello-World",
  "full_name": "octocat/Hello-World",
  "owner": {
    "login": "octocat",
    "id": 1,
    "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
    "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "private": false,
  "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World",
  "description": "This your first repo!",
  "fork": false,
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World",
  "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/{archive_format}{/ref}",
  "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/assignees{/user}",
  "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/blobs{/sha}",
  "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/branches{/branch}",
  "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/collaborators{/collaborator}",
  "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/comments{/number}",
  "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits{/sha}",
  "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/compare/{base}...{head}",
  "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contents/{+path}",
  "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contributors",
  "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/deployments",
  "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/downloads",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/events",
  "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/forks",
  "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/commits{/sha}",
  "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/refs{/sha}",
  "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/tags{/sha}",
  "git_url": "git:github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git",
  "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/comments{/number}",
  "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/events{/number}",
  "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues{/number}",
  "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/keys{/key_id}",
  "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/labels{/name}",
  "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/languages",
  "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/merges",
  "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/milestones{/number}",
  "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
  "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls{/number}",
  "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases{/id}",
  "ssh_url": "git@github.com:octocat/Hello-World.git",
  "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/stargazers",
  "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/statuses/{sha}",
  "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/subscribers",
  "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/subscription",
  "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/tags",
  "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/teams",
  "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/trees{/sha}",
  "clone_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git",
  "mirror_url": "git:git.example.com/octocat/Hello-World",
  "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/hooks",
  "svn_url": "https://svn.github.com/octocat/Hello-World",
  "homepage": "https://github.com",
  "language": null,
  "forks_count": 9,
  "forks": 9,
  "stargazers_count": 80,
  "watchers_count": 80,
  "watchers": 80,
  "size": 108,
  "default_branch": "master",
  "open_issues_count": 0,
  "open_issues": 0,
  "is_template": false,
  "topics": [
    "octocat",
    "atom",
    "electron",
    "api"
  ],
  "has_issues": true,
  "has_projects": true,
  "has_wiki": true,
  "has_pages": false,
  "has_downloads": true,
  "archived": false,
  "disabled": false,
  "visibility": "public",
  "pushed_at": "2011-01-26T19:06:43Z",
  "created_at": "2011-01-26T19:01:12Z",
  "updated_at": "2011-01-26T19:14:43Z",
  "permissions": {
    "pull": true,
    "push": false,
    "admin": false
  },
  "allow_rebase_merge": true,
  "template_repository": {
    "id": 1296269,
    "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMjk2MjY5",
    "name": "Hello-World-Template",
    "full_name": "octocat/Hello-World-Template",
    "owner": {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "private": false,
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World-Template",
    "description": "This your first repo!",
    "fork": false,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template",
    "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/assignees{/user}",
    "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/branches{/branch}",
    "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/comments{/number}",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/commits{/sha}",
    "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/contents/{+path}",
    "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/contributors",
    "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/deployments",
    "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/downloads",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/events",
    "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/forks",
    "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/git/commits{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/git/refs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_url": "git:github.com/octocat/Hello-World-Template.git",
    "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/issues/comments{/number}",
    "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/issues/events{/number}",
    "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/issues{/number}",
    "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/keys{/key_id}",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/labels{/name}",
    "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/languages",
    "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/merges",
    "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/milestones{/number}",
    "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
    "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/pulls{/number}",
    "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/releases{/id}",
    "ssh_url": "git@github.com:octocat/Hello-World-Template.git",
    "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/stargazers",
    "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/statuses/{sha}",
    "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/subscription",
    "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/tags",
    "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/teams",
    "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/git/trees{/sha}",
    "clone_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World-Template.git",
    "mirror_url": "git:git.example.com/octocat/Hello-World-Template",
    "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World-Template/hooks",
    "svn_url": "https://svn.github.com/octocat/Hello-World-Template",
    "homepage": "https://github.com",
    "language": null,
    "forks": 9,
    "forks_count": 9,
    "stargazers_count": 80,
    "watchers_count": 80,
    "watchers": 80,
    "size": 108,
    "default_branch": "master",
    "open_issues": 0,
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "is_template": true,
    "license": {
      "key": "mit",
      "name": "MIT License",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/mit",
      "spdx_id": "MIT",
      "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZW1pdA==",
      "html_url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/mit"
    },
    "topics": [
      "octocat",
      "atom",
      "electron",
      "api"
    ],
    "has_issues": true,
    "has_projects": true,
    "has_wiki": true,
    "has_pages": false,
    "has_downloads": true,
    "archived": false,
    "disabled": false,
    "visibility": "public",
    "pushed_at": "2011-01-26T19:06:43Z",
    "created_at": "2011-01-26T19:01:12Z",
    "updated_at": "2011-01-26T19:14:43Z",
    "permissions": {
      "admin": false,
      "push": false,
      "pull": true
    },
    "allow_rebase_merge": true,
    "temp_clone_token": "ABTLWHOULUVAXGTRYU7OC2876QJ2O",
    "allow_squash_merge": true,
    "delete_branch_on_merge": true,
    "allow_merge_commit": true,
    "subscribers_count": 42,
    "network_count": 0
  },
  "temp_clone_token": "ABTLWHOULUVAXGTRYU7OC2876QJ2O",
  "allow_squash_merge": true,
  "delete_branch_on_merge": true,
  "allow_merge_commit": true,
  "subscribers_count": 42,
  "network_count": 0,
  "license": {
    "key": "mit",
    "name": "MIT License",
    "spdx_id": "MIT",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/mit",
    "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZW1pdA=="
  },
  "organization": {
    "login": "octocat",
    "id": 1,
    "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
    "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
    "type": "Organization",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "parent": {
    "id": 1296269,
    "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMjk2MjY5",
    "name": "Hello-World",
    "full_name": "octocat/Hello-World",
    "owner": {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "private": false,
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "description": "This your first repo!",
    "fork": false,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World",
    "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/assignees{/user}",
    "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/branches{/branch}",
    "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/comments{/number}",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits{/sha}",
    "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contents/{+path}",
    "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contributors",
    "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/deployments",
    "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/downloads",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/events",
    "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/forks",
    "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/commits{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/refs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_url": "git:github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/comments{/number}",
    "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/events{/number}",
    "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues{/number}",
    "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/keys{/key_id}",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/labels{/name}",
    "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/languages",
    "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/merges",
    "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/milestones{/number}",
    "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
    "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls{/number}",
    "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases{/id}",
    "ssh_url": "git@github.com:octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/stargazers",
    "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/statuses/{sha}",
    "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/subscription",
    "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/tags",
    "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/teams",
    "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/trees{/sha}",
    "clone_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "mirror_url": "git:git.example.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/hooks",
    "svn_url": "https://svn.github.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "homepage": "https://github.com",
    "language": null,
    "forks_count": 9,
    "stargazers_count": 80,
    "watchers_count": 80,
    "size": 108,
    "default_branch": "master",
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "is_template": true,
    "topics": [
      "octocat",
      "atom",
      "electron",
      "api"
    ],
    "has_issues": true,
    "has_projects": true,
    "has_wiki": true,
    "has_pages": false,
    "has_downloads": true,
    "archived": false,
    "disabled": false,
    "visibility": "public",
    "pushed_at": "2011-01-26T19:06:43Z",
    "created_at": "2011-01-26T19:01:12Z",
    "updated_at": "2011-01-26T19:14:43Z",
    "permissions": {
      "admin": false,
      "push": false,
      "pull": true
    },
    "allow_rebase_merge": true,
    "temp_clone_token": "ABTLWHOULUVAXGTRYU7OC2876QJ2O",
    "allow_squash_merge": true,
    "delete_branch_on_merge": true,
    "allow_merge_commit": true,
    "subscribers_count": 42,
    "network_count": 0,
    "license": {
      "key": "mit",
      "name": "MIT License",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/mit",
      "spdx_id": "MIT",
      "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZW1pdA==",
      "html_url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/mit"
    },
    "forks": 1,
    "open_issues": 1,
    "watchers": 1
  },
  "source": {
    "id": 1296269,
    "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMjk2MjY5",
    "name": "Hello-World",
    "full_name": "octocat/Hello-World",
    "owner": {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "private": false,
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "description": "This your first repo!",
    "fork": false,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World",
    "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/assignees{/user}",
    "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/branches{/branch}",
    "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/comments{/number}",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits{/sha}",
    "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contents/{+path}",
    "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contributors",
    "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/deployments",
    "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/downloads",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/events",
    "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/forks",
    "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/commits{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/refs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_url": "git:github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/comments{/number}",
    "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/events{/number}",
    "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues{/number}",
    "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/keys{/key_id}",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/labels{/name}",
    "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/languages",
    "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/merges",
    "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/milestones{/number}",
    "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
    "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls{/number}",
    "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases{/id}",
    "ssh_url": "git@github.com:octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/stargazers",
    "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/statuses/{sha}",
    "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/subscription",
    "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/tags",
    "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/teams",
    "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/trees{/sha}",
    "clone_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "mirror_url": "git:git.example.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/hooks",
    "svn_url": "https://svn.github.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "homepage": "https://github.com",
    "language": null,
    "forks_count": 9,
    "stargazers_count": 80,
    "watchers_count": 80,
    "size": 108,
    "default_branch": "master",
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "is_template": true,
    "topics": [
      "octocat",
      "atom",
      "electron",
      "api"
    ],
    "has_issues": true,
    "has_projects": true,
    "has_wiki": true,
    "has_pages": false,
    "has_downloads": true,
    "archived": false,
    "disabled": false,
    "visibility": "public",
    "pushed_at": "2011-01-26T19:06:43Z",
    "created_at": "2011-01-26T19:01:12Z",
    "updated_at": "2011-01-26T19:14:43Z",
    "permissions": {
      "admin": false,
      "push": false,
      "pull": true
    },
    "allow_rebase_merge": true,
    "temp_clone_token": "ABTLWHOULUVAXGTRYU7OC2876QJ2O",
    "allow_squash_merge": true,
    "delete_branch_on_merge": true,
    "allow_merge_commit": true,
    "subscribers_count": 42,
    "network_count": 0,
    "license": {
      "key": "mit",
      "name": "MIT License",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/mit",
      "spdx_id": "MIT",
      "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZW1pdA==",
      "html_url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/mit"
    },
    "forks": 1,
    "open_issues": 1,
    "watchers": 1
  }
}
```

If the repository is public, you won't need any permission to access those datas.

Now the repository is private, you'll need to use your [PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.0/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) in the request **headers** to get access to them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it is organized on GitLab, but GitHub Actions are created not per project but per repository, so maybe this will work for you. You can find variables from `github` context [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context) where - `github.repository` gives you:

> The owner and repository name. For example, Codertocat/Hello-World